# How to prove convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \log(1 + 1/n^2)$

Tags: analysis, limits

I need to see whether

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \log\left(1 + \frac{1}{n^2}\right) $$

is converging or diverging. It is pretty obvious that this series is converging, and I believe I can proof it with the comparison test, but I am not totally sure how.

Comment: What is the natural candidate to compare it with?

Comment: $\ln(1+t)\sim_0t$.

Answer (score 2):

HINT:
$$\log\left(1+\frac{1}{n^2}\right)\leq\frac{1}{n^2}.$$

Comment: Cheers, so I didn't look for the obvious...when dealing with logarithms, do you generally compare it to non-logarithmic functions?

Comment: In these cases, the expansions of $\log(1\pm x)$ are your friends.